# WP REST API returns empty posts despite entries in wp_posts

Tags: rest-api

Using WP API to query posts. There are many entries in wp_posts, but the API always returns an empty array.

Request: `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/`

Response: `[]`

Request: `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/3553`

Response:

```
{
    "code": "rest_post_invalid_id",
    "message": "Invalid post ID.",
    "data": {
        "status": 404
    }
}
```

Yet, querying MySQL directly:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM wp_posts;
```

returns 391

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `wp_posts` where id = 3553;
```

returns 1

Is there some inherent filtering in the API? I am stumped here.

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Not by default, no. Do you have a security plugin or similar that might be doing this?

Comment: And can you confirm to us by showing us that DB row that it is the post you expected, and that it's of the correct post type? ( `post` )